# xarray: averaging adjacent values in a 1D DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am new to xarray (and python) so your patience is appreciated!

I have a 1D DataArray ("p") of length 35 and I want to return an array containing the averages of adjacent values in p (so of length 34). However, when I try doing this using the simple indexing shown below, I'm returned an array of length 33 that is equal to p[1:-1] – not what I want!

```
>>> ds_va = xr.open_dataset(va_filename)
>>> p = ds_va['plev']
>>> p.shape
(35,)
>>> np.shape((p[:-1] + p[1:])/2) 
(33,)
```

I understand what is going on: xarray is using automatic alignment so that the result of my binary operation is the intersection of the coordinate labels. What is a good way around this issue?

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: It sounds like a rolling mean would work here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#rolling-window-operations